# PowerApps - How to show different forms? (New/Edit/View)

Tags: powerapps-forms

I came across this guide. but when I try to add the code I always get an error.
Do you guys have an idea why this happens or how I can work around that?
[image: Code that throws error]

[image: Forms]

Comment: What guide? Post a link, so we see the instructions, too.

Comment: Which of the commands is responsible for the error? Remove the commands, and add them one by one to see which one throws the error.